# Problems with converting string to float while using dictionary within a list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I am trying to get the following code to print out all the rows in the csv file, but limit the columns in each print out to the value of the key "Name", as well as do a separate calculation of the two dictionary keys named "Spent Past 12 Months" and "Spent Past 6 Months". I want to subtract 6 months from 12 for each person, and print out that value as "collectionBalance". I have tinkered around with the "for" loop all day and I am at a loss of how to properly convert the values associated with those two keys before calculating and printing them. And those two values are both considered strings, so I was trying to strip them of the quotation marks as well. The error being thrown at me is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "customer_regex.py", line 11, in <module>
    collectionsBalance = float(data[count]["Spent Past 12 Months"].strip()) - float(data[count]["Spent Past 6 Months"].strip())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$6030.52'
```

---

```
import csv
import re
data = []
count = 0


with open('customerData.csv') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    data.append(row)
    collectionsBalance = float(data[count]["Spent Past 12 Months"].strip()) - float(data[count]["Spent Past 6 Months"].strip())
    print(data[count]["Name"] + collectionsBalance)
    count = count + 1
```

Comment: Hey! Are you open to try a new library? Have you heard about Pandas? It can handle things like these in easy-to-read way.

Comment: Have you tried removing the dollar sign? That's your problem not the quotes

Comment: Hey! Sharing a sample in text-format would be really helpful too!

Comment: The problem is the `$` character. Also, note that floating point numbers are ill suited for monetary calculations. Python has a `Decimal` numeric type which is often used instead. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html

Comment: This is a tinker-around kind of project. It's for school, no real objective other than practicing manipulating the given file and data. I decided to do this with it. But thank you, that dollar sign was just what I needed to fix this.

Comment: @AntonvBR This is the readout I got after fixing:                                   
Dennis Rodriguez 1905.61
Ethan Jimenez 7898.95
Clifford Byrd 7577.40
Mister Gavin Rowe 4974.32
Dr. Lena Flowers 8314.40
Gertrude Bowers 5383.31
Mister Gerald Copeland 6871.24
Dr. Lina Perez 7622.22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove dollar sign with `strip('$')` eg:

```
collectionsBalance = float(data[count]["Spent Past 12 Months"].strip('$')) - float(data[count]["Spent Past 6 Months"].strip('$'))
```